# Как прочитать данные из Excel файла только из нескольких столбцов?

Tags: python-3.x, excel, pandas, dataframe, csv

Дело в том, то что данные в моём csv-файле записаны таким образом: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Конкретно из этого файла я хочу считать данные со столбиков "Дата" и "Цена last".
Пробую классическим образом:

```
df = pd.read_csv('filename.csv')
```

Получаю на выход ошибку:

```
FileNotFoundError: File b'filename.csv' does not exist
```

Comment: пропишите полный путь к файлу. И еще вы можете уточнить в вопросе какой у вас формат файла Excel или CSV?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Команда:

```
df = pd.read_csv('filename.csv')
```

пытается прочитать `'filename.csv'` из текущей директории. Если вы работаете в IDE типа iPython / Jupyter / PyCharm / etc. то текущей директорий может оказаться не та которую вы ожидаете.

Самый надежный способ указывать полный путь к файлу:

```
df = pd.read_csv(r'c:\data\filename.csv')
```

---

чтобы прочитать только необходимые столбцы воспользуйтесь параметром [`usecols`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html):

```
df = pd.read_csv(r'c:\data\filename.csv', usecols=['Дата', 'Цена last'])
```

Если у вас Excel файл то:

```
df = pd.read_excel(r'c:\data\filename.xlsx', usecols=['Дата', 'Цена last'])
```